# Props don't update when input changes in component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this simple component where I try to bind props both ways but it only works one way. When I change the text in my input fields, it shows 'Initial property 1' to be the value of myprop1 although I changed the input. What could be wrong?

**My component**

```
Vue.component('simple-input', {

    template: `
        <div>
            <input type="text" :myprop1="myprop1" :value="myprop1" @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)">
            <input type="text" :myprop2="myprop2" :value="myprop2" @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)">
        </div>
    `,

    props: ['myprop1', 'myprop2']

});
```

**main.js**

```
new Vue({
    el: '#root',

    data: {
        myprop1: 'Initial property 1',
        myprop2: 'Initial property 2',
    },

    methods: {
        showMe()
        {
            alert('prop1 - ' + this.myprop1);
            alert('prop2 - ' + this.myprop2);

            this.myprop1 = 'new value';
            this.myprop2 = 'new value';
        }
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<simple-input :myprop1="myprop1" :myprop2="myprop2"></simple-input>

<button @click="showMe">Show me!</button>
```

Comment: because I don't know how if I have 2 props - one for each input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's 2 main issues:

1. Your child component is emitting the `input` event for both inputs. You need to emit different events so that you can distinguish between them in the parent component. Also:

- `:myprop1="myprop1"` does nothing to the input element, there's no such `myprop1` prop/attribute on inputs.
- `myprop` is a terrible name, use `value` instead.

  ```es6
  Vue.component('simple-input', {
    template: `
      <div>
        <input type="text" :value="value1" @input="$emit('update:value1', $event.target.value)">
        <input type="text" :value="value2" @input="$emit('update:value2', $event.target.value)">
      </div>
    `,
    props: ['value1', 'value2'],
  });
  ```

2. In your parent component, you need to listen to the `update:value1` and `update:value2` events so that you can receive the new values from the child.

   ```vue
    <simple-input
      :value1="value1"
      :value2="value2"
      @update:value1="value1 = $event"
      @update:value2="value2 = $event"
    ></simple-input>
   ```

In fact, because we used the naming convention `update:prop` for the event, we can use the [`sync`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier) modifier to make the binding 2-way. So it becomes just:

```
<!-- language: lang-vue -->

    <simple-input
      :value1.sync="value1"
      :value2.sync="value2"
    ></simple-input>
```